# Cryptocurrency miner in JavaScript (alternative to CoinHive)

Tags: open-source, javascript, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

Is there any open source cryptocurrency miner in JS? CoinHive is proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community wiki. You can extend it if you like.*

---

There are some open source Bitcoin miners:

- [Hash me if you can](https://github.com/derjanb/hamiyoca)
- [jsMiner](https://github.com/jwhitehorn/jsMiner)
- [Bitcoin Miner](https://github.com/thorsteinson/bitcoin-miner)
- [JavaScript Emscripten Bitcoin Miner](https://github.com/altermarkive/JavaScript-Emscripten-Bitcoin-Miner)
- [CryptoNoter](https://github.com/cryptonoter/CryptoNoter)
- [Nimiq](https://github.com/nimiq-network/core)